# How to set up NameVirtualHost

Tags: server, apache2

I'm trying to run seperate websites from one ip address. I've got the connection coming through a router that has port forwards to an apache2 server. I need to set up a NameVirtualHost system so apache can determine which files to look for for different domain names.

Any advise would be appreciated. I was pretty sure that namevirtualhost was largely out of use.

Answer (score 0):

Look into configuring

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.conf

You need a file normally called default.conf there defining virtualhosts like so...

```
<VirtualHost yourIPaddress:80 >

    ServerName www.yourdomainname.here
    ServerAlias yourdomainname.here
    ServerAdmin <yourmail address>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/{your webroot folder}

    <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/{your webroot folder} >
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

     # set your own filename #
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/logging_filename_errorlog.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel error

    # set your own filename #
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/logging_filename.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

Comment: Substitute yourdomainname.here for your domain, and set your DocumentRoot. There are other way of doing it. And I am sure there will be some comments and elaborations.. I hope this helps. note: this has some logfile configuration and PHP configuration in it. You might want to change those according to your situation.

Comment: I have tried, I've got three virtual host files at the moment each listening on different ports. But don't think I can get my Domain Name host to route to different ports. It's something to do with name virtual hosts.

Comment: do you have a file called ports.conf ? in /etc/apache2 it should look something like this Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
 Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
 Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

Answer (score 0):

do you have a file called ports.conf ? in /etc/apache2 it should look something like this:

```
Listen 80
```

Listen 443

Listen 443

## vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

Comment: yes, the files there, but i don't think i can get my domain name host to point to specific ports.

Comment: the "Listen 443" is for SSL by the way so that is not always there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to point to specific ports.

```
<VirtualHost PUT.YOUR.IP.HERE:80 >

    ServerName www.domainname1.com
    ServerAlias domainname1.com
    ServerAdmin someemail@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/{rootdir of site 1}
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost PUT.YOUR.IP.HERE:80 >

    ServerName www.domainname2.com
    ServerAlias domainname2.com
    ServerAdmin someemail@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/{rootdir of site 2}
</VirtualHost>
```

replace "PUT.YOUR.IP.HERE" with your own IP the virtual host will direct apache2 towards correct root folder for each of the "ServerName" and "ServerAlias"... note that the "port" is set to :80 on both Virtual hosts entries. So no need to reconfigure. If this doesn't work I suggest checking the Apache logging.